# Export data from SQL Server Database to Access Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I want to transfer some data From SQL Server database to Access database using C# , in SQL Server DB I have one datetime column which the format is : `dd/MM/yyyy` . When the data is transformed to Access , the date Column will be in a format like `MM/dd/yyyy`. How can I resolve this problem?

```
AccessInsertCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@" INSERT INTO[Ordonnance]
( [N_Ordonnance], [N_ASS], [NomASS], [PrénomASS], [Cat_ASS], [DateFinContrat],
[Nom Ayant], [Prénom Ayant], [Sexe Ayant], [Date_Naiss] , [Lien Parenté],
[Date Saisie], [Date_Soin], [Pathologie], [Nom_Méd], [Statut Assurée],
[Carte N°=], [DateValidation], [DateFinTraiCh], [N_Fact], [Date_Fact],
[N_Bord], [Nom_Phar], [Montant], [Nbre Vignettes], [Total], [Nbre Ord])
VALUES(" + Ordonnance.N_ORD.ToString() + ","
+ Ordonnance.NUM_ASSURE.ToString() + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.NOM_ASSURE.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.PRENOM_ASSURE.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.CAT_ASS.ToString() + "'" + "," +
(Ordonnance.DATE_FIN_CONTRAT == "" ? DBNull.Value : ((object)("#" +
    Ordonnance.DATE_FIN_CONTRAT + "#")))
+ "," + "'" + Ordonnance.NOM_AYANT_DR.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.PRENOM_AYANT_DR.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + (Ordonnance.SEXE.ToString() == "" ? "null" : Ordonnance.SEXE.ToString())
+ "'" + ","
+ (Ordonnance.DATE_NAISS == null ? DBNull.Value : ((object)("#" +
    Ordonnance.DATE_NAISS + "#"))) +
"," + "'" + Ordonnance.LIEN_PARENTE.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ ("#" + Ordonnance.DATE_SAISIE+"#") +
"," + (Ordonnance.DATE_SOINS == null ? DBNull.Value : ((object)("#" +
    Ordonnance.DATE_SOINS + "#")))
+ "," +  (Ordonnance.PATHOLOGIE == "" ? "null" :
    Ordonnance.PATHOLOGIE.ToString()) + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.MEDECIN.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.STATUT_ASSURE.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ "'" + (Ordonnance.NUM_CARTE_CHRON.Equals("null") ? "null" : ((object)
    (Ordonnance.NUM_CARTE_CHRON))) + "'" +
"," + (Ordonnance.DATE_VALIDATION.Equals("null") ? "null" : ((object)("#" + 
    Ordonnance.DATE_VALIDATION + "#"))) + ","
+ (Ordonnance.DATE_FIN_TRAITEMENT_CHRON.Equals("null") ? "null" : ((object)("#" + 
    Ordonnance.DATE_FIN_TRAITEMENT_CHRON + "#"))) +
"," + (Ordonnance.NUM_FACTURE == null ? DBNull.Value : ((object) 
   (Ordonnance.NUM_FACTURE))) + ","
+ (Ordonnance.DATE_FACTURE == null ? DBNull.Value : ((object)("#" +
    Ordonnance.DATE_FACTURE + "#"))) +
"," + (Ordonnance.NUM_BORDEREAU == null ? DBNull.Value : ((object)
    (Ordonnance.NUM_BORDEREAU))) + ","
+ "'" + Ordonnance.NOM_PHARMACIE.ToString() + "'" + ","
+ (Ordonnance.MONTANT.ToString()).Replace(",", ".") + ","
+ Ordonnance.NBR_VIGNETTE.ToString()
+ "," + "9999999"
+ "," + Ordonnance.NBRE_ORD.ToString() + ")");
AccessInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that `DateSoin` which is an Object, is not formatted correctly like I want.

Comment: If you parametise your insert statement, then you will be able to pass the date as a date, instead of a string representation, and your problem will disappear.

Comment: Yep. the problem isn't the string representation of the date, the problem is that you *are* using string to represent a `date`. Pass it as the correct datatype (a `date`, I assume) by using parameters and the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you can simply fill a DataTable and pass it to an OleDbDataAdapter, which will generate the  SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter?view=netframework-4.8